# Set number input max based on the sum of 4 inputs using jquery and reset quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I followed this thread [Set number input max based on the sum of 4 inputs using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730572/set-number-input-max-based-on-the-sum-of-4-inputs-using-jquery) and the code below works as expected:

```
$("input[type='number'].wapo-product-qty").val(0); 
$("input[type='number'].wapo-product-qty").change(function () {
$.each($("input[type='number'].wapo-product-qty"), function (index, element) {
    var total = 0;
    $.each($("input[type='number'].wapo-product-qty").not($(element)), function 
(innerIndex, innerElement) {
        total += parseInt($(innerElement).val());
    });
    if ($(element).val() > 6 - total) {
        alert("The total value for all inputs can not exceed 6");
                  $(element).val(0);
        return false;
    } else {
        $(element).attr("max", 6 - total);
        }
    });
});
```

Here full HTML --> https://pastebin.com/DjX8Kkt1

But I need the quantity selector to start from 0 and not from 1.

I added this for that, but I don't know is the best approach:

```
 $("input[type='number'].wapo-product-qty").val(0);
```

Once the condition of the maximum number of quantities is reached, the fields for which the quantity has not been selected with the selector are reset to 0.

For example in my case:

```
4 input fields: 

0 -> change to 2
0 -> change to 2
0 -> change to 2
0 -> change to 1 -> we are over 6, condition reached
```

But the last input it remains 1, so I would like to reset to 0 for this reason.

Thanks

Comment: share `html` code too.

Comment: Edited the question @BhargavChudasama, added to pastebin because it is quite long.

Comment: you need to reset value 0 if input onchange value is greater than 6 right?

Comment: Yes, right. Once quantity 6 is reached, all options that exceed must be reset.

Comment: all input will be 0 or only exceed will 0?

Comment: Only input that exceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code with an updated javascript function.

call function `onchange of input` and get sum of all input and check condition

```js
$("input[type='number'].wapo-product-qty").val(0);

function getQtyTotal(event) {
  var total = 0;
  // total += parseInt(event.target.value);
  $.each($("input[type='number'].wapo-product-qty"), function(index, element) {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  //console.log(total);
  if (total > 6) {
    alert("The total value for all inputs can not exceed 6");
    event.target.value = 0;
    return false;
  } else {
    if (event.target.value > 6) {
      event.target.setAttribute("max", 6 - total);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options default-closed per-row-5 grid">
  <p class="wapo-addon-description">Choose product</p>
  <div id="yith-wapo-option-1-0" class="yith-wapo-option selection-multiple       " data-replace-image="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yith-wapo-1-0" class="yith-proteo-standard-checkbox" name="yith_wapo[][1-0]" value="product-8061-1" data-price="0" data-price-sale="0" data-price-type="fixed" data-price-method="free" data-first-free-enabled="no" data-first-free-options="5"
      data-addon-id="1" style="display: none;">
    <label for="yith-wapo-1-0" style="width: 33%;">
        <img src="#" data-id="8061">
        <div>
            <!-- PRODUCT NAME -->
            Product 1       
            <br>
            <div class="option-add-to-cart">
                <input type="number" class="wapo-product-qty" data-product-id="8061" name="yith_wapo_product_qty[1-0]" value="1" min="1" max="1254" style="min-width: 50px; width: 5em; margin-right: 10px; float: left;" onChange="getQtyTotal(event);">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="yith-wapo-option-1-1" class="yith-wapo-option selection-multiple       " data-replace-image="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yith-wapo-1-1" class="yith-proteo-standard-checkbox" name="yith_wapo[][1-1]" value="product-8028-1" data-price="0" data-price-sale="0" data-price-type="fixed" data-price-method="free" data-first-free-enabled="no" data-first-free-options="5"
      data-addon-id="1" style="display: none;">
    <label for="yith-wapo-1-1" style="width: 33%;">
        <img src="#" data-id="8028">
        <div>
            <!-- PRODUCT NAME -->
            Product 2               
            <br>
            <div class="option-add-to-cart">
                <input type="number" class="wapo-product-qty" data-product-id="8028" name="yith_wapo_product_qty[1-1]" value="1" min="1" max="1180" style="min-width: 50px; width: 5em; margin-right: 10px; float: left;" onChange="getQtyTotal(event);">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="yith-wapo-option-1-2" class="yith-wapo-option selection-multiple       " data-replace-image="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yith-wapo-1-2" class="yith-proteo-standard-checkbox" name="yith_wapo[][1-2]" value="product-8026-1" data-price="0" data-price-sale="0" data-price-type="fixed" data-price-method="free" data-first-free-enabled="no" data-first-free-options="5"
      data-addon-id="1" style="display: none;">
    <label for="yith-wapo-1-2" style="width: 33%;">
        <img src="#" data-id="8026">
        <div>
            <!-- PRODUCT NAME -->
            Product 3       
            <br>
            <div class="option-add-to-cart">
                <input type="number" class="wapo-product-qty" data-product-id="8026" name="yith_wapo_product_qty[1-2]" value="1" min="1" max="991" style="min-width: 50px; width: 5em; margin-right: 10px; float: left;" onChange="getQtyTotal(event);">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="yith-wapo-option-1-3" class="yith-wapo-option selection-multiple       " data-replace-image="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yith-wapo-1-3" class="yith-proteo-standard-checkbox" name="yith_wapo[][1-3]" value="product-7943-1" data-price="0" data-price-sale="0" data-price-type="fixed" data-price-method="free" data-first-free-enabled="no" data-first-free-options="5"
      data-addon-id="1" style="display: none;">
    <label for="yith-wapo-1-3" style="width: 33%;">
        <img src="#" data-id="7943">
        <div>
            <!-- PRODUCT NAME -->
            Product 4
            <br>
            <div class="option-add-to-cart">
                <input type="number" class="wapo-product-qty" data-product-id="7943" name="yith_wapo_product_qty[1-3]" value="1" min="1" max="955" style="min-width: 50px; width: 5em; margin-right: 10px; float: left;" onChange="getQtyTotal(event);">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
```